# Unix : List children processes for a given pid

Tags: linux, shell, ps

What I need is, given a process id, list all his children without any clutter (table header, other columns than the pid)

What I have is :

```
ps h --ppid $PID
```

Which gives me:

```
26277 pts/13   S+     0:10 cmd1
26280 pts/13   S+     0:10 cmd2
...
```

Using h allow me to hide the table header.

Is there a way to tell ps to not print the `pts/13   S+     0:10 cmd` part in order to get a list of children process ids separated by carriage return?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
ps h --ppid $PID -o pid
```

Comment: Thank you, it works :) I thought of using -o before, but in my tests ps threw me a syntax error. (I think I had concurrent switches when I tried it...).